# App is crashing when taken picture using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE on some devices?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have facing some strange behaviour with my Application : On Some device like samsung sony Onplus my application work fine but some device like

1. Lenovo a7000
2. redmi x

Application is crashing and I am getting this [image] error

My code is :

```
private void captureImageFromCamera() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {

            Uri photoURI;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            } else {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constant.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am creating image file

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_";

    //  File storageDir = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/PhotoGallery/");

    File storageDir = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES );

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.d("imageFileName", imageFileName);
    Log.d("imageFile", image.toString());

    return image;

}
```

This is my OnActivityResult:

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            setPic();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

}

And Here I am setting Pic by sending to another activity:

```
private void setPic() throws IOException {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditImageActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("mCurrentPhotoPath", compressImage(mCurrentPhotoPath,MainActivity.this));



    intent.putExtra("CalledBy","Camera");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

There are another person who faced the same problem . Have the found the answer yet. I tired out a lot of question on stackoverflow but not of them work for me ,
Please let me know about this issue why in some devices is works fine and some devices that I mention above not,
Any Help is appreciated

Comment: What is the Android Version of the phone where it crashes??

Comment: Hey @Xenolion I mentioned above model and version is Marshmallow and I provide all run time permission.

Comment: add super in onActivityResult

Comment: @AnkitAman You didn't get my point I am having issue on some device some device It's working fine.

Comment: Yes for sure I added provider properly . And I mentioned above the devices name.

Comment: Issues like this always happen when there are changes due toan upgrade of android versions. Check if you check runtime permission correctly for your case WRITE and READ external storage. Check if there is any vital deprecated methods.....

Comment: try to add custom width and height to the picture, and test..

Comment: I checked them all . It's working fine on same version device like sony,Samsung @Xenolion

Comment: Hey You found any solution for this problem, Im also getting this problem in motorola device

Answer (score 0):

I found two solution to your problem [**1st One**](https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker/issues/9#issuecomment-241974674) and [2nd One](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media) is below

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Create a File reference to access to future access
    photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);  

    // wrap File object into a content provider
    // required for API >= 24
    // See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher
    Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyActivity.this, "com.codepath.fileprovider", photoFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider); 

    // If you call startActivityForResult() using an intent that no app can handle, your app will crash.
    // So as long as the result is not null, it's safe to use the intent.
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Start the image capture intent to take photo
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

where

```
public File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
    // Get safe storage directory for photos
    // Use `getExternalFilesDir` on Context to access package-specific directories.
    // This way, we don't need to request external read/write runtime permissions.
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
       Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
    }

    // Return the file target for the photo based on filename
    File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);

    return file;
}
```

I am also facing this problem. New devices require `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`  and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` and for devices with **Api > 24** you have to implement [**provider**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher)